Unwanted extra vertical lines for the last row in my longtable
In the below code, I get some unwanted vertical lines for the first cell at the last. How can I get rid of them ?
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

%set margins
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
% *** TABLE PACKAGES ***
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{boldline} 
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
 \usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
 \usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % For row colors

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3} % Adjust row height
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm} % Thicker lines for section separations
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt} % Adjust column spacing

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[2]{m{#1}} % Adjust text wrapping
\newcolumntype{L}[2]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % Left-aligned column
\newcolumntype{C}[2]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}   % Center-aligned column
\newcolumntype{X}[2]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % Wrappable column
\usepackage{adjustbox} % Add this to your preamble
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{| L{3.25cm} | L{2.25cm} | L{3cm} | L{2cm} | L{5cm} |}

\caption{Few studies reported the design changes on gas cyclones}
            
            \hline
            \makecell{Article} &   \makecell{Target Part} & \makecell{Design\\ Modification} & \makecell{$d_{50}$ Range\\ (\si{\micro\metre})} &\makecell{Summary of\\ Findings}\\\hline
       \endhead

\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Design changes on a cyclone to function as a Particle Separator ($d_{50}$ \leq 3 $\mu m$)}                                         \\ \hline
     
        \citet{yoshida1993}& Inlet section &Inlet guide plate& 0.45-0.75 &
        Controlled the cut point by adjusting the guide plate location to alter the inlet clearance\\\hline

     \citet{yoshida2005}& Inlet section &Secondary injection flow& 0.7-1.25 &
        The secondary flow injection was placed in the proximity of the upper plate. High tangential velocities are reported in the region close to the secondary injection flow.\\\hline
        
         \citet{HIRAIWA2013}& Inlet section  &Compressed air injection. Secondary flow & 1.1-1.75 &
        Higher tangential and axial velocities are reported in the upper cylindrical part because of secondary flow injection.\\\hline
    
         \citet{Laminarizer2017}& Inlet section  &15 horizontal laminarizer cylinders  inserted in the inlet & 1.4-2.07 &
        Laminarizer induces higher gas velocities near the outer part of the inlet. Increased pressure drop, and higher particle separation efficiency were reported as the greater number of particles were found in the outer part of the entrance\\\hline
        
        \citet{MISIULIA2015,MISIULIA2017}& Inlet section  &Inlet angle with a helical-roof inlet & 1.2-3.75 &
         An increase in inlet angle increases the cut size with a reduction in cyclone efficiency and pressure drop coefficient.\\\hline          
  
         \citet{YOSHIDA2001}& Conical section &Double cone for Iinoya cyclone & 0.8-0.95 &
        10\% lower pressure drop than compared with the conventional designs\\\hline

         \citet{HUANG2018}& Conical section  &Various splits on the conical section & 0.83-1.35 &
        Fine particles are removed before they exit through the overflow through the split. The overall separation efficiency increased from 74.5 to 80.7\% .\\\hline  
        
         \citet{WAKIZONO2015}& Vortex finder  & Optimised the ring structure on the vortex finder & 0.67-2 &
        The modified design eliminates the re-circulation zones near the vortex finder area. Thus, high particle collection efficiencies and lower pressure drop were reported.\\\hline 
       \citet{yoshida1995}& Apex section &Blow down& - &
        Performed CFD simulations to track the particle behavior in a blow-down cyclone. Observed reduction in cutpoint.\\\hline
                
    
 \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Design changes on a cyclone to function as a Particle Classifier ($d_{50}$ 1-30$\mu m$)}                                         \\ \hline      
        
         \citet{YOSHIDA2013}& Apex section  &Apex cone shape + Blow-down & \textbf{2-38.07} &
        A movable apex cone reduces the re-entrainment of particles from the dust box. \\\hline
        
         \citet{Oshitari2015,Oshitari2017}& Apex section  &The particles are classified between the sloppy channel of inner and outer collection boxes using the blow-up air flow & \textbf{18-29} &
        It was demonstrated that cut size is a strong function of the main inlet flow through the entrance irrespective of the blow-up flow rate. However with the increase in blow-up flow the sharpness of the separation increases.\\\hline        
     \label{Tab:GasCyloneDesignChanges}    
        \end{longtable}
\end{document}



I get errors when I add in \begin/\end{document}.  Can you complete this so that it compiles?  And maybe trim out the unnecessary stuff?  But if you're using booktabs, it would say that all vertical lines are unwanted.

Just curious: Why do you like to make the vertical and horizontal rules in your tables so thick, to the degree that they're almost oppressively thick?

you have a one-cell final row just containing \label{Tab:GasCyloneDesignChanges}   place the label in an existing row rather than make a new row, which is forcing the extra lines

There's no need to employ a longtable, as one can easily fit all of the material on a single page. The key is to widen columns 3 and 5 from 3cm and 5cm to 4.25cm and 7.75cm, respectively, and conversely to make columns 1, 2, and 4 narrower, while also assuring that the width of the table doesn't exceed \textwidth.
Since your code loads the booktabs package, I would also make use of its machinery, use fewer but well-spaced horizontal rules, and get rid of all vertical rules in order to give the table a much more open and inviting "look".
Incidentally, I can't help but remark that the preamble of your test document is wildly overgrown and in need of some serious weeding, pruning, and other forms of clean-up.

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

%set margins
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{makecell,booktabs,longtable,natbib,
            array,siunitx,ragged2e,calc}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}} % Left-aligned column
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1}} % Centered column

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p] % place on a page by itself
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % default: 6pt

\caption{Few studies reported the design changes on gas cyclones}
\label{Tab:GasCyloneDesignChanges}

\smallskip
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
   l  
   L{\widthof{Conical}}  
   L{4.25cm}  
   L{\widthof{$d_{50}$ Range\,}}  
   L{7.75cm} }

\toprule
\makecell{Article} & \makecell{Target\\ Part} & 
\makecell{Design\\ Modification} & 
\makecell{$d_{50}$ Range\\ (\si{\micro\metre})} & 
\makecell{Summary of Findings}\\
\midrule

\multicolumn{5}{c}{Design changes on a cyclone to function as a Particle Separator ($d_{50} \leq \qty{3}{\micro\meter}$)}\\ 
\midrule
     
\citet{yoshida1993}& Inlet section &Inlet guide plate& 0.45--0.75 &
Controlled cut point by adjusting guide plate location to alter inlet clearance\\

\addlinespace

\citet{yoshida2005}& Inlet section &Secondary injection flow& 0.7--1.25 &
Secondary flow injection was placed in proximity of the upper plate. High tangential velocities are reported in region close to secondary injection flow.\\

\addlinespace

\citet{HIRAIWA2013}& Inlet section &Compressed air injection. Secondary flow & 1.1--1.75 &
Higher tangential and axial velocities are reported in upper cylindrical part because of secondary flow injection.\\

\addlinespace
    
\citet{Laminarizer2017}& Inlet section &15 horizontal laminarizer cylinders  inserted in the inlet & 1.4--2.07 &
Laminarizer induces higher gas velocities near outer part of inlet. Increased pressure drop and higher particle separation efficiency were reported as a greater number of particles was found in outer part of entrance.\\

\addlinespace

\citet{MISIULIA2015,MISIULIA2017}& Inlet section &Inlet angle with a helical-roof inlet & 1.2--3.75 &
An increase in inlet angle increases cut size with a reduction in cyclone efficiency and pressure drop coefficient.\\
  
\citet{YOSHIDA2001}& Conical section &Double cone for Iinoya cyclone & 0.8--0.95 &
10\% lower pressure drop than compared with conventional designs.\\

\addlinespace

\citet{HUANG2018}& Conical section &Various splits on the conical section & 0.83--1.35 &
Fine particles are removed before they exit through overflow through split. Overall separation efficiency increased from 74.5 to 80.7\%.\\

\addlinespace  

\citet{WAKIZONO2015}& Vortex finder & Optimised the ring structure on the vortex finder & 0.67--2 &
Modified design eliminates re-circulation zones near vortex finder area. Thus, high particle collection efficiencies and lower pressure drop were reported.\\

\addlinespace 

\citet{yoshida1995}& Apex section &Blow down& -- &
Performed CFD simulations to track the particle behavior in a blow-down cyclone. Observed reduction in cutpoint.\\

\midrule  
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Design changes on a cyclone to function as a Particle Classifier ($d_{50}$ 1--30\,\unit{\micro\meter})}\\ 
\midrule      

\citet{YOSHIDA2013}& Apex section & Apex cone shape + Blow-down & 2--38.07 &
A movable apex cone reduces re-entrainment of particles from dust box. \\

\addlinespace

\citet{Oshitari2015,Oshitari2017}& Apex section &Particles are classified between sloppy channel of inner and outer collection boxes using blow-up air flow & 18--29 &
It was demonstrated that cut size is a strong function of main inlet flow through entrance irrespective of blow-up flow rate. However with the increase in blow-up flow sharpness of separation increases. \\       
\bottomrule

\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}


Sorry, your code example is very erroneous, from missing \begin{document},\end{document}, missed packages and use obsolete siunitx syntax.  Beside this, your code example is far from be minimal. I try to fix your code, but I'm not sure, if succeed in this.
I would use longtblr of tabularray package. With it MWE is much shorter and clear:
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[ a4paper,hmargin=2cm,vmargin={2cm,3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext}  % new
\usepackage{microtype}  % new

\usepackage{ragged2e}   % new
\usepackage{tabularray} % new
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,
                siunitx}% missed
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{natbib}     % missed


\begin{document}
{
\RenewDocumentCommand\TblrAlignLeft{}{\RaggedRight}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Few studies reported the design changes on gas cyclones},
  label = {Tab:GasCyloneDesignChanges}
                    ]{hlines, vlines,
                      colsep  = 4pt,
                      colspec = {X[1.2,l] Q[l] X[1.8,l]
                                 Q[c] X[3,l]},
                      cells  = {font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
                      row{1} = {c, m},
                      rowsep = 3pt,
                      rowhead=1
                      }
Article &   {Target\\ Part}
            &   {Design\\ Modification}
                &   {$d_{50}$ Range\\ (\unit{\micro\metre})}
                    &   {Summary of\\ Findings}   
                    \\
\SetCell[c=5]{c}    Design changes on a cyclone to function as a Particle Separator ($d_{50} \leq \qty{3}{\micro\meter}$)
    &   &   &   &   \\
Oshitari et all. [39,40] %\citet{yoshida1993}
        &   Inlet section 
            &   Inlet guide plate
                &   0.45-0.75
                    &   Controlled the cut point by adjusting the guide plate location to alter the inlet clearance
                    \\
\citet{yoshida1993}
        &   Inlet section 
            &   Inlet guide plate
                &   0.45-0.75 
                    &   Controlled the cut point by adjusting the guide plate location to alter the inlet clearance
                        \\
\citet{yoshida2005}
        &   Inlet section 
            &   Secondary injection flow
                &   0.7-1.25 
                    &   The secondary flow injection was placed in the proximity of the upper plate. High tangential velocities are reported in the region close to the secondary injection flow.
                        \\
\citet{HIRAIWA2013}
    &   Inlet section  
        &   Compressed air injection. Secondary flow 
            &   1.1-1.75 
                &   Higher tangential and axial velocities are reported in the upper cylindrical part because of secondary flow injection.
                        \\             
\citet{Laminarizer2017}
    &   Inlet section  
        &   15 horizontal laminarizer cylinders  inserted in the inlet 
            &   1.4-2.07 
                &   Laminarizer induces higher gas velocities near the outer part of the inlet. Increased pressure drop, and higher particle separation efficiency were reported as the greater number of particles were found in the outer part of the entrance
                    \\
\citet{MISIULIA2015,MISIULIA2017}
        &   Inlet section  
            &   Inlet angle with a helical-roof inlet 
                &   1.2-3.75 
                    &   An increase in inlet angle increases the cut size with a reduction in cyclone efficiency and pressure drop coefficient.
                        \\
\citet{YOSHIDA2001}
    &   Conical section 
        &   Double cone for Iinoya cyclone 
            &   0.8-0.95
                &   \qty{10}{\%} lower pressure drop than compared with the conventional designs
                            \\
\citet{HUANG2018}
    &   Conical section  
        &   Various splits on the conical section 
            &   0.83-1.35
                &   Fine particles are removed before they exit through the overflow through the split. The overall separation efficiency increased from 74.5 to 80.7\% .
                            \\         
\citet{WAKIZONO2015}
    &   Vortex finder  
        &   Optimised the ring structure on the vortex finder 
            &   0.67-2 
                &   The modified design eliminates the re-circulation zones near the vortex finder area. Thus, high particle collection efficiencies and lower pressure drop were reported.
                    \\                
\citet{yoshida1995}
    &   Apex section 
        &   Blow down
            & - 
                &   Performed CFD simulations to track the particle behavior in a blow-down cyclone. Observed reduction in cutpoint.
                    \\
\SetCell[c=5]{c}   Design changes on a cyclone to function as a Particle Classifier $d_{50}$ (\qtyrange{1}{30}{\micro\metre})
    &   &   &   &   \\*
\citet{YOSHIDA2013}
    &   Apex section  
        &   Apex cone shape + Blow-down 
            &   \textbf{2-38.07} 
                 &   A movable apex cone reduces the re-entrainment of particles from the dust box. 
                     \\*
\citet{Oshitari2015,Oshitari2017}
    &   Apex section  
        &   The particles are classified between the sloppy channel of inner and outer collection boxes using the blow-up air flow 
            &   \textbf{18-29} 
                &   It was demonstrated that cut size is a strong function of the main inlet flow through the entrance irrespective of the blow-up flow rate. However with the increase in blow-up flow the sharpness of the separation increases.
                    \\
        \end{longtblr}
}
\end{document}


Edit:
Ups, in editing OP code I lost first multicolumn cell. Now is added.
Better filling of cells can be obtain with use small font size. In this case, table can be fit on one page, so instead longtable you can use talltblr. With more compact cells contents I suggest to omit all vertical  lines and the most of horizontal (as is suggested in @mico answer):
\usepackage[ a4paper,hmargin=2cm,vmargin={2cm,3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext}  % new
\usepackage{microtype}  % new

\usepackage{ragged2e}   % new
\usepackage{tabularray} % new
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,
                siunitx}% missed
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{natbib}     % missed


\begin{document}
{
\RenewDocumentCommand\TblrAlignLeft{}{\RaggedRight}
    \begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Few studies reported the design changes on gas cyclones},
  label = {Tab:GasCyloneDesignChanges}
                    ]{colsep  = 4pt,
                      colspec = {X[1.2,l] Q[l] X[1.8,l]
                                 Q[c] X[3,l]},
                      cells  = {font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
                      row{1} = {c, m},
                      row{2-Z} = {rowsep = 3.3pt}
                      }
    \toprule
Article &   {Target\\ Part}
            &   {Design\\ Modification}
                &   {$d_{50}$ Range\\ (\unit{\micro\metre})}
                    &   {Summary of\\ Findings}
                    \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[c=5]{c}    Design changes on a cyclone to function as a Particle Separator ($d_{50} \leq \qty{3}{\micro\meter}$)
    &   &   &   &   \\
    \midrule
Oshitari et all. [39,40] %\citet{yoshida1993}
        &   Inlet section
            &   Inlet guide plate
                &   0.45-0.75
                    &   Controlled the cut point by adjusting the guide plate location to alter the inlet clearance
                    \\
\citet{yoshida1993}
        &   Inlet section
            &   Inlet guide plate
                &   0.45-0.75
                    &   Controlled the cut point by adjusting the guide plate location to alter the inlet clearance
                        \\
\citet{yoshida2005}
        &   Inlet section
            &   Secondary injection flow
                &   0.7-1.25
                    &   The secondary flow injection was placed in the proximity of the upper plate. High tangential velocities are reported in the region close to the secondary injection flow.
                        \\
\citet{HIRAIWA2013}
    &   Inlet section
        &   Compressed air injection. Secondary flow
            &   1.1-1.75
                &   Higher tangential and axial velocities are reported in the upper cylindrical part because of secondary flow injection.
                        \\
\citet{Laminarizer2017}
    &   Inlet section
        &   15 horizontal laminarizer cylinders  inserted in the inlet
            &   1.4-2.07
                &   Laminarizer induces higher gas velocities near the outer part of the inlet. Increased pressure drop, and higher particle separation efficiency were reported as the greater number of particles were found in the outer part of the entrance
                    \\
\citet{MISIULIA2015,MISIULIA2017}
        &   Inlet section
            &   Inlet angle with a helical-roof inlet
                &   1.2-3.75
                    &   An increase in inlet angle increases the cut size with a reduction in cyclone efficiency and pressure drop coefficient.
                        \\
\citet{YOSHIDA2001}
    &   Conical section
        &   Double cone for Iinoya cyclone
            &   0.8-0.95
                &   \qty{10}{\%} lower pressure drop than compared with the conventional designs
                            \\
\citet{HUANG2018}
    &   Conical section
        &   Various splits on the conical section
            &   0.83-1.35
                &   Fine particles are removed before they exit through the overflow through the split. The overall separation efficiency increased from 74.5 to 80.7\% .
                            \\
\citet{WAKIZONO2015}
    &   Vortex finder
        &   Optimised the ring structure on the vortex finder
            &   0.67-2
                &   The modified design eliminates the re-circulation zones near the vortex finder area. Thus, high particle collection efficiencies and lower pressure drop were reported.
                    \\
\citet{yoshida1995}
    &   Apex section
        &   Blow down
            & --
                &   Performed CFD simulations to track the particle behavior in a blow-down cyclone. Observed reduction in cutpoint.
                    \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[c=5]{c}   Design changes on a cyclone to function as a Particle Classifier $d_{50}$ (\qtyrange{1}{30}{\micro\metre})
    &   &   &   &   \\*
    \midrule
\citet{YOSHIDA2013}
    &   Apex section  
        &   Apex cone shape + Blow-down
            &   \textbf{2-38.07}
                &   A movable apex cone reduces the re-entrainment of particles from the dust box.
                    \\*
\citet{Oshitari2015,Oshitari2017}
    &   Apex section
        &   The particles are classified between the sloppy channel of inner and outer collection boxes using the blow-up air flow
            &   \textbf{18-29}
                &   It was demonstrated that cut size is a strong function of the main inlet flow through the entrance irrespective of the blow-up flow rate. However with the increase in blow-up flow the sharpness of the separation increases.
                    \\
    \bottomrule
        \end{talltblr}
}
\end{document}



Well, the code snippet provided by user3454353 is not at all a minimal-working-example, but I'll try my best to solve the problem.
I got dozens of errors and warnings with the original code. Relevant data (such as the bibliography references) are missing. I removed non-required content and prepared this snippet:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

% set margins
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

% packages for tables and caption
\usepackage{tabularx}  % tables with custom columntypes
\usepackage{caption}  % enables \captionsetup
\usepackage{longtable}  % enables environment
\usepackage{makecell}  % enables command for use in tables

% custom table setup
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3} % adjust row height
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm} % thicker lines for section separations
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt} % adjust column spacing
\newcolumntype{L}[2]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % left-aligned column

\begin{document}
    \captionsetup{width=\linewidth} % make the caption fill the whole width
    \begin{longtable}{| L{3cm} | L{2.25cm} | L{3cm} | L{2cm} | p{4cm} | }
        \caption{Few studies reported the design changes on gas cyclones}\\
        %
        \hline
        \makecell{Article} &   \makecell{Target Part} & \makecell{Design\\ Modification} & \makecell{$d_{50}$ Range\\ ($\mu m$)} &\makecell{Summary of\\ Findings}\\\hline
        \endhead
        %
        \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Design changes on a cyclone to function as a Particle Separator ($d_{50} \leq 3 \mu m$)}\\ \hline
        A & Inlet section &Inlet guide plate& 0.45-0.75 &
        Controlled the cut point by adjusting the guide plate location to alter the inlet clearance\\\hline
        B & Inlet section &Secondary injection flow& 0.7-1.25 &
        The secondary flow injection was placed in the proximity of the upper plate. High tangential velocities are reported in the region close to the secondary injection flow.\\\hline
        C& Inlet section  &Compressed air injection. Secondary flow & 1.1-1.75 &
        Higher tangential and axial velocities are reported in the upper cylindrical part because of secondary flow injection.\\\hline
        D & Inlet section  &15 horizontal laminarizer cylinders  inserted in the inlet & 1.4-2.07 &
        Laminarizer induces higher gas velocities near the outer part of the inlet. Increased pressure drop, and higher particle separation efficiency were reported as the greater number of particles were found in the outer part of the entrance\\\hline
        E & Inlet section  &Inlet angle with a helical-roof inlet & 1.2-3.75 &
        An increase in inlet angle increases the cut size with a reduction in cyclone efficiency and pressure drop coefficient.\\\hline
        F & Conical section &Double cone for Iinoya cyclone & 0.8-0.95 &
        10\% lower pressure drop than compared with the conventional designs\\\hline
        G & Conical section  &Various splits on the conical section & 0.83-1.35 &
        Fine particles are removed before they exit through the overflow through the split. The overall separation efficiency increased from 74.5 to 80.7\% \\\hline
        H & Vortex finder  & Optimised the ring structure on the vortex finder & 0.67-2 &
        The modified design eliminates the re-circulation zones near the vortex finder area. Thus, high particle collection efficiencies and lower pressure drop were reported.\\\hline
        I & Apex section &Blow down& - &
        Performed CFD simulations to track the particle behavior in a blow-down cyclone. Observed reduction in cutpoint.\\\hline
        %
        \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Design changes on a cyclone to function as a Particle Classifier ($d_{50}$ 1-30$\mu m$)}\\ \hline
        J & Apex section  &Apex cone shape + Blow-down & \textbf{2-38.07} &
        A movable apex cone reduces the re-entrainment of particles from the dust box. \\\hline
        L & Apex section  &The particles are classified between the sloppy channel of inner and outer collection boxes using the blow-up air flow & \textbf{18-29} &
        It was demonstrated that cut size is a strong function of the main inlet flow through the entrance irrespective of the blow-up flow rate. However with the increase in blow-up flow the sharpness of the separation increases.\\\hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}

The problem of the unexpected vertical lines is not present for this code. Page 2 looks like this:


The MWE has several bugs, but I am trying to give advice on some things that the questioner might take care of to avoid unexpected results:

Don't use blank lines in tables (they are interpreted as paragraph breaks). You can use commented out blank lines to visually organize your table code (as I did in my code snippet).
The total width of the longtable in the original code was to large. I reduced it to fit to the page until the most right final vertical border of the table was visible.
As far as I understand, a \\ is required after the \caption{...}. Hence, to have the caption at top of your longtable, the first line in the longtable reads \caption{Some caption}\\.
Reduce the number of packages that you are including with \usepackage to the relevant ones. This is relevant not only for creating an MWE, but also for your actual document, since you will loose overview and, therefore, loose control of what is happening. I tend to make notes after the \usepackage{...} lines in my preamble, where I mention why I imported this and how it influences my document.

